# From the Michael Hartl book, the route "/static_pages/help" won't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Whenever I try to navigate to [this link](https://6b282af9eebc44a4940fcfd7a239f6f3.vfs.cloud9.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/static_pages/help),
it does not change to this view. It just continues to display the root route.

Please can someone point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end
end


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    def hello
    render html: "hello, world!"
    end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/home'

  get 'static_pages/help'

  root 'application#hello'
end
```

Comment: i have tried ...amazon.comstatic_pages/help and just /static_pages etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the concerned controller, when done there is no reason for the following not to work :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'application#hello'
  get 'static_pages/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
  get 'static_pages/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
end
```

I don't know if everyone's does this, but it seems to me preferred to put the root atop.